# Expand subfolder into parent folder

Tags: windows-explorer

Is it possible to expand a subfolder, so that all of the files located within it were automatically moved to the parent folder rather than having to manually go in and cut and paste?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the subfolder a Symbolic Link. Open up a command console with admin rights and type `mklink /d "Path\to\subfolder" "path\to\parent"`.

Comment: I tried this - it doesn't work - Am i missing something? - I'm trying this in Win 7 - FYI

Comment: Make sure the subfolder **doesn't** exist. Create the symlink, then move everything into it.

Comment: But the OP question says he already has got.the sub folders and he wants them to move to the parent folder level without the need to exploring the sub folder each time

Comment: That can be done after the symlink is created.